# sencha touch messagebox unclickable

Tags: android, sencha-touch

In sencha touch we have a little problem with a messagebox. It looks that it's something with android 4.3. On the most devices it's works perfect, but on a device with android 4.3, when the user press the button, the messagebox will not disappear.

```
Ext.define('TestBuild.view.MyPanel', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',

config: {
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            itemId: 'mybutton',
            text: 'MyButton'
        }
    ],
    listeners: [
        {
            fn: 'onMybuttonTap',
            event: 'tap',
            delegate: '#mybutton'
        }
    ]
},

onMybuttonTap: function(button, e, eOpts) {
    console.log("Test");
    Ext.Msg.alert("TEST");
}

});
```

Comment: check if the callback is fired:
Ext.Msg.alert('Title', 'TEST', function(){
 console.log('button press');
});

Comment: I have tested but on the htc one (Android 4.3) it doesn't work. On other phones in Eclipse I saw the logged text. In my opinion is it something in the combination of Android 4.3 and Sencha Touch.

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution:

Add Following line before showing Alert Box:

**Ext.Msg.defaultAllowedConfig.showAnimation = false;**

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
Ext.define('Ext.Component', {
        override: 'Ext.Component',
        show: function (animation) {
            return this.callParent([false]);
        },
        hide: function (animation) {
            return this.callParent([false]);
        }
    });
```

I found the solution on http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?262324-Sencha-Messagebox-and-Overlay-Problems-on-HTC-One-Browser

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution here: https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?284450-MessageBox-cannot-be-closed-under-some-circumstances.&p=1040686&viewfull=1#post1040686

```
Ext.override(Ext.MessageBox, {    
    hide:  function() {
       if (this.activeAnimation && this.activeAnimation._onEnd) {
        this.activeAnimation._onEnd();
       }
       return this.callParent(arguments);
   }
});
```

This works for me for touch 2.4.2