# Sencha ExtJS msg alert won't dissapear

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm sending messages on my app with:

```
Ext.Msg.alert('Unable to register');
```

The box pops up perfectly, and also dissapears after pressing 'OK' a few times, but after a few tries the box stays after pressing 'OK' (I can interact with the app though afterwards, the box just won't go away).

Anyone experienced this problem before who knows how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Sounds like you are creating too many of them and they just hide one behind another. Try logging their creation, make sure you have only one box out there when pressing 'OK'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sencha touch messagebox unclickable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024726/sencha-touch-messagebox-unclickable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, experienced the same a while ago. I fixed it by adding the following lines to my app as a temporary solution. Never founded a real solution though.

```
Ext.Msg.defaultAllowedConfig.showAnimation = false
Ext.Msg.defaultAllowedConfig.hideAnimation = false
```

[More information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024726/sencha-touch-messagebox-unclickable) and possible duplicate..

Comment: Thanks alot! Couldn't find that other one sorry about that.